# Construct/Destruct custom gradle task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm totally new in gradle/groovy. I want to create custom task which will do some stuff. My first problem is how to do something when task finishes its job? Can I override doFirst/doLast closures? Maybe I can override some method which will do something at the beginning and at the end?

This is my "task"

```
import java.nio.file.Files

class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    File buildDir
    File tempDir

    public MyCustomTask() {
        super()
        buildDir = project.getBuildFile().getParentFile()
        tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(buildDir.toPath(), "MyCustomTask").toFile()
    }

    @TaskAction
    def build() {
        println("test");
    }

    // I want to delete tempDir ater task execution

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [temporaryDir](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:temporaryDir) location and let Gradle clean up for you?

Comment: The temp dir needs to be created (and deleted) in the task action; otherwise, it will be created for *each invocation* of Gradle, even if the task at hand isn't run. Instead of deleting it, it's probably better to put the directory beneath `build` (as Tim said).

Answer (score 1):

As it says [on the official Gradle help forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/is_there_anything_like_finally_in_gradle_i_want_to_do_some_clean_up_no_matter_whether_task_succeeds_or) (where someone asked this same question), you should either

- wrap your `build()` code in a `try...finally` block
- or write your custom task folder to the `build` directory so it gets cleaned when the user does `gradle clean`

Comment: Thanks. I've used temporaryDir as Ben Manes wrote and try{}catch{} to clean it.